# Find $f'(x)$ when $f(x) = x^2 \cos(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus

Find $f'(x)$ when
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2\cos(\frac{1}{x}),& x \neq 0\\
0, &x = 0\end{cases}$$

Ok, I know the derivative of $f$ and it is $2x\cos(\frac{1}{x})+\sin(\frac{1}{x})$. My question is, am I only supposed to find the derivative here or evaluate this at $0$? I mean what exactly is the reason behind this piecewise function if I don't evaluate this at $0$? Does it make sense? Also, when a question says to find out whether or not $f$ is differentiable for a piecewise function like this, what are we supposed to do, find $f'(x)$ or evaluate at $f'(0)$? I am sorry if these are very elementary level questions. But, I always get confused on terms like these. Any explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should use definition of derivative

Comment: You need to use the limit definition of the derivative to answer this question.

Comment: Ok! so $f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(f(h)-f(0)}{h})$? If so, then why doesn't the question say find $f'(0)$?

Comment: Reread the chapter on "Continuity".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\ne 0$, use usual rules for evaluating derivatives.

For $x=0$, use definition of $f'(0)$:
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\cos\frac1h-0}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} h\cos\frac1h = 0.
$$
We cannot use formula for $f'(x)$ with $x\ne 0$; $x^2\cos\frac1x$ is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but the question should say find $f'(0)$ instead of f'(x), shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jellyfish Finding $f'(x)$ means finding the value of $f'$ (or determining that it does not exist) at **all** values of $x$.  If you only compute $f'(x)$ for $x\ne 0$, that doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: When x is not 0, the derivative is as you said in your question.

Comment: @Jellyfish Derivative is a derivative, at $x=0$ or not. "Instead" is not right word. For $x\ne 0$ you have got answer.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, Never mind. I think I got it. Thanks for your detail explanation.

Comment: @Jellyfish, yep. Find $f''(0)$ for better understanding (hint: it doesn't exists)

Comment: @JonnJonzz:  It should say "In conclusion $f '(x) =$" rather than "In conclusion $f '(0) =$".  (The system would not let me edit it.)

Comment: Ahh, nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

Let  $$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2\cos(\frac{1}{x}),& x \neq 0\\
0, &x = 0\end{cases}$$

As you said in your question, when $x$ is not 0, we have $$f^{'}(x)=2x\cos(\frac{1}{x})+\sin(\frac{1}{x})$$

When $x$ *is* 0, we must use the limit definition of the derivative. That is, $$f^{'}(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\dfrac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$$ Since when evaluating this limit, $$0+h\neq 0$$ we have that $$f(0+h)=f(h)=h^2\cos(\frac{1}{h})$$

Therefore, $$f^{'}(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h\cos{\dfrac{1}{h}}=0$$

In conclusion, $$f^{'}(x)=$$ \begin{cases}
2x\cos(\frac{1}{x})+\sin(\frac{1}{x}),& x \neq 0\\
0, &x = 0\end{cases}

Comment: Surely, when $x$ is not 0, we have $$f^{'}(x)=2x\cos(\frac{1}{x})+\frac{1}{x^2}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$$

Comment: @GuyCorrigall You've dropped the $x^2$ term in the product rule, why?

Comment: @JonnJozz Of course you are correct: my careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, Using first principle $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ $$\implies f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x+h}\right)-x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{h}$$ It is clear from given data that function, $f(x)$ changes its definition at $x=0$, hence to check the differentiability of function $f(x)$ at $x=0$, let's calculate the left hand derivative (LHD) & the right hand derivative (RHD) at $x=0$ as follows $$\implies LHD=\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{(0+h)^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{0+h}\right)-(0)^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)}{h}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{h^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}h\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$$$$=\lim_{h\to 0}(-h)\cos\left(\frac{1}{-h}\right)=-\lim_{h\to 0}h\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)=0$$  $$\implies RHD=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{(0+h)^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{0+h}\right)-(0)^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{0}\right)}{h}$$ $$=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{h^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}h\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$$$$=\lim_{h\to 0}(h)\cos\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)=0$$   Thus, we find that $LHD=RHD=0$, hence function $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, we have $$f'(0)=0$$
While, $f'(x)$ for $x\neq 0$ can be simply determined using product rule as follows $$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$ $$=2x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right)$$ $$=2x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$